# Hide siblings on hover javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a function that watches an element and when hovered or focused on, hides it's siblings.

I've written this

```
var hotSpotDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-hotspot');
hotSpotDiv.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
    this.classList.add('active');
})

hotSpotDiv.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
    this.classList.remove('active');
})
```

Which works but I'm stuck trying to think of how I can hide the elements that do not have the `active` class added on hover.

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but any particular reason you don't want to accomplish this with `CSS` using `:hover` and the sibling (`+`) selector?

Comment: Nevermind-- I see now you want to hide all siblings-- I can see where that would be problematic using `CSS`.  Can you add your markup?  That would be helpful in providing the pertinent CSS to answer your question.

Comment: Note that the code you've shown won't work to add an event listener, because `hotSpotDiv` is a list and doesn't have an `.addEventListener()` method.

Answer (score 2):

This code is ...not great.. and I made some presumptions about your scenario, but it should hopefully give you a good jumping off point.

```js
var hotSpotDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-hotspot');
var i;
function hotspotMouseEnter(e) {
    this.classList.add('active');
    this.parentNode.classList.add('active');
}

function hotspotMouseLeave(e) {
    this.classList.remove('active');
    this.parentNode.classList.remove('active');
}

for (i=0; i<hotSpotDivs.length; i++) {
  hotSpotDivs[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', hotspotMouseEnter);
  hotSpotDivs[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', hotspotMouseLeave); 
}
```

```css
.the-container.active>.custom-hotspot {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.the-container.active>.custom-hotspot.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="the-container">
 <p class="custom-hotspot">hotspot 1</p>
 <p class="custom-hotspot">hotspot 2</p>
 <p class="custom-hotspot">hotspot 3</p>
 <p class="custom-hotspot">hotspot 4</p>
 <p class="custom-hotspot">hotspot 5</p>
 <p class="custom-hotspot">hotspot 6</p>
</div>
```

Comment: *"This code is ...not great"* - I think this is a fairly clean solution. I was thinking about looping over all the siblings to hide or show them individually, but a class on the parent is much neater. Nice work.

Comment: @nnnnnn -- thanks!  In the real world I might have looked into delegating the event listeners for efficiency's sake, and the `this.parentNode` feels a little flimsy, but hopefully it gives Brendan something to build on :)

Comment: Yeah, for DOM traversal I'm used to the ease of jQuery's `.closest()` to allow for "parent" elements potentially being higher up the tree than the literal parent. Could always just select the parent directly by its class or id instead (and give it one if it doesn't already have one like yours does).

Comment: This works really well. I'm working on a build without jQuery cause I found I was relying on it and we have projects coming up where they are a 'no, no'. For whatever reason I just couldn't think of the best way to do this with Vanilla. Like @nnnnnn said, It's nice and clean.

Comment: @Brendan - Great, glad to help!  Good luck on going jQuery-less!